# How to return JSON from APIFunction without string encapsulation?

Tags: cloud-deploy, json-format, apifunction

I am trying to get an APIFunction to send valid JSON.  This is my demo function.

```
CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction[{"y" -> "Number"}, 
  ExportString[{"TestData" -> {"bob1" -> #y, "bob2" -> "abc"}}, 
    "JSON", "Compact" -> True] &], "EPCtest3", 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Run from a URL, e.g."*www.wolfram. ... /EPCtest3?y=123*" produces this

> ```
> "{\"TestData\":{\"bob1\":123,\"bob2\":\"abc\"}}"
> ```

However, this [JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) says it is invalid.  It is ok if formatted like so:

> ```
> {"TestData":{"bob1":123,"bob2":"abc"}}
> ```

The receiving code is expecting JSON, e.g.

```
var documentResponse = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(documentResponse);
```

I can output valid JSON in regular Mathematica using the Notation package, (not ideal though).  However, that doesn't work from the cloud.

```
Needs["Notation`"]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper[":"], Rule ]
{"TestData" -> {"bob1" -> 123, "bob2" -> "abc"}}
```

> ```
> {"TestData" : {"bob1" : 123, "bob2" : "abc"}}
> ```

E.g. Doesn't work on the cloud.

[image]

Any help on sending JSON from the APIFunction appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify `"String"` as result type for the `APIFunction`, as in `APIFunction[{"y" -> "Number"}, ExportString[...] &, "String"]`. Otherwise you will get the input-form like representation of the resulting string

Comment: Great! Thanks.:-)

Answer (score 2):

As [Lukas Lang said](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206488/how-to-return-json-from-apifunction-without-string-encapsulation#comment531107_206488),

> You need to specify `"String"` as result type for the `APIFunction`, as in `APIFunction[{"y" -> "Number"}, ExportString[...] &, "String"]`. Otherwise you will get the input-form like representation of the resulting string.

The function now works:

```
CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction[{"y" -> "Number"}, 
  ExportString[{"TestData" -> {"bob1" -> #y, "bob2" -> "abc"}}, 
    "JSON", "Compact" -> True] &, "String"], "EPCtest3", 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```